# Encrypt isomorphic web app state w/ sensitive data – Client (JavaScript React Redux) to Server (Java Spring Nashorn React)?

Tags: spring, reactjs, encryption, jwt, nashorn

How can I store sensitive state data in the browser? How can I populate the UI with sensitive data when rendering on the server?

Suppose I have an isomorphic web application.
I am using a stateless Java (Spring) back-end with a JavaScript front-end (React, Redux).
I am doing authentication with JWTs (oauth2: auth_token, refresh_token, localStorage).

The Java back-end can render views with a Nashorn Engine and React.
The Javascript font-end can render views with React in the browser.
I have an isomorphic UI between the Java back-end and JavaScript front-end.  Given the same properties, they will render identical views using the same React components.

For clarification on the referred to “state” within the flowing text, I mean the state of the user’s view.
For example, a form wizard with three steps.  On the third step, we must keep accurate history of the user’s input from first and second step.  I do this on the client with Redux.

Note, I absolutely do not want to track state on the server-side.
I am controlling state on the client with Redux and for good reason.
There will be far to many state variables and events to continually flood the server with requests to update the state.
I can not react to every UI event with a request to the server.
If you think that state should be tracked on the server, that is great.  I am not doing that.

Due to the isomorphic nature of the UI, a user can render identical views in two ways:

1. Through the back-end (Java, Nashorn Engine, React) - A user does a
   browser refresh (state is lost).
2. Through the front-end (JavaScript, React) - The JavaScript was loaded prior to user navigation (state is maintained).

In other words, the first page load always happens on the server with Java, Nashorn Engine, and React.

When a user refreshes the browser, the back-end will render the page and is unaware of the UI state.
I am storing non-sensitive information in the client’s localStorage to repopulate the UI when this happens.
However, I also need to securely store sensitive information in the client’s localStorage and/or a cookie to repopulate the UI in the same manner.

If I store the state in a cookie, I could repopulate the UI on the server-side. That sounds wonderful.

I am aware of JWEs.  They seem to be riddled with exploits and I don’t feel they are safe enough for this particular data.

Although similar, I think this would be safer than JWE:

1. On the server, generate a pool of RSA public and private key pairs.
2. On the client, encrypt sensitive data with AES using generated key from random salt, random pass-phrase, and random iv.
3. On the client, with the RSA public key provided by the server, encrypt the hex-encoded random salt, hex-encoded random pass-phrase, and hex-encoded random iv used to generate the AES key.
4. Appended RSA encrypted secrets to AES encrypted data and store the data as cookie.
5. When a view is going to be rendered by the server, look for the cookie, decrypt the cookie, populate the state, render view from the server.

Comment: Here is the [isomorphic template project](https://github.com/TransEmpiric/iso-web-template). We have a ton code that can encrypt and decrypt via AES and RSA from client to server and vice versa.  We have not published the encryption code yet, because it is too slow atm.